# How to calculate IQ from bhatia battery test?

Tags: measurement, intelligence

How to find out IQ from bhatia battery test? Suppose time for each of the 5 subtests is noted down. What are the steps to reach at an IQ value from here?

Comment: For second and third test it is from 5 to 8. Not 6 to 10.

Answer (score 7):

I hadn't heard of the Bhatia measure before. A little research (see [page 42 of Sharma and Sharma](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=f8fJu3jSXJ0C&pg=PA42&lpg=PA42&dq=Bhatia%27s+Battery+of+Performance+Tests&source=bl&ots=844j20AWvN&sig=fDChH_SPJuBjlU6TmOfDB9g6T6w&hl=en&sa=X&ei=amhYU56NHMXOkQWkx4CwCQ&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Bhatia%27s%20Battery%20of%20Performance%20Tests&f=false)) explains that it is a performance based measure of ability for children in India. In general, you should obtain the test manual to learn about the recommended scoring procedure. A quick Google suggests it might be available from here: http://www.npcindia.com/

#### Reference

- *Experimental Psychology*  By Ram Nath Sharma, Rachana Sharma

Answer (score 2):

First you need to score for each of the five subtests.

1. Koh's block test:
   first 5 block - if completed in less than one minute give 2 mark and if between 1 and 2 minute give 1 mark or else zero
   block 6 to 10 : if completed in less than one minute give 3 marks, between 1 and 2 minute give 2 mark and between 2 and 3 minutes give 1 mark. failure zero
2. Alexander's pass along test: 
   first four: less than one minute 2 marks, between 1 and 2 minutes give 1 mark
   6 to 10 test : less than one minute 3 marks, 1 to 2 minutes 2 marks, and between 2 and 3 minute - 1 mark. failure zero
3. Pattern drawing:
   first four: less than one minute 2 marks, between 1 and 2 minutes give 1 mark
   6 to 10 test : less than one minute 3 marks, 1 to 2 minutes 2 marks, and between 2 and 3 minute - 1 mark. failure zero
4. picture construction test:
   1st to 3rd test: less than one minute 2 marks, between 1 and 2 minutes give 1 mark
   4 and 5 test: less than one minute 3 marks, 1 to 2 minutes 2 marks, and between 2 and 3 minute - 1 mark. failure zero
5. Immediate Memory test
   there are forward and reverse
   for each set of forward and reverse if there is atleast one correct sequence give marks
   (this you need to recheck)

once you get all the scores added together that is your raw score. Now compare your raw score to Bhatia's Table where you will get the IQ score against the age of the individual and raw score.

Comment: Welcome to CogSci and thanks for your answer. Could you add your sources to allow other users to background read on your material?